# Effect of phase current on magnetic flux density in synchronous machines

Tags: magnetic-flux, synchronous-motor

I am working on a project on synchronous machines and I am testing different phase current values and observing the magnetic flux density in different parts of the machine, such as teeth, stator yoke, air gap, rotor, and the permanent magnets. I am observing a general increasing trend in flux density as phase current increases. The only relationship I can think of is the following:

[image: formula]

Where

[image: formula]

Therefore, as phase current increases, so does the flux density due to an increase in the flux intensity. However, it seems to be inaccurate to me as the above equations hold for DC current, as far as I know. Therefore, is this explanation accurate, or is there a more correct one? Also, I am noticing a weird trend in the magnet's density, shown in the figure below. What causes this drop in the density? Does it have to do anything with the magnet's permeability?

[image]